# How do I pass the invoice ID with PayPal REST API?

Tags: python, api, paypal

I followed the guide here: https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal/python?interactive=OFF&env=sandbox

I doesn't say how I will be able to determine which invoice was paid!

Comment: Is the question "How do I pass the invoice ID with PayPal REST API" as the title says?  Or is it "How do i determine which invoice was paid?" as it says in the body?

Comment: This question is entirely dependent on an external link, which appears to be dead (SSL error, non-SSL redirects to PayPal home). I believe it can be closed as off-topic, since it cannot presently be useful to future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The payment id from step 2 is returned in step 4.

Comment: Correct but how will I tell the invoice ID? The client my open several invoice in different tabs concurrently.

Comment: @AdamSilver: on this question, it looks like you had remaining doubts, but accepted this anyway. Is there any more information that you could offer to edit into this answer? I wonder if it is rather brief at the moment.

Comment: @halfer: Seriously? That was 5 years ago. I don't even remember asking the question lol.